# GStreamer Unable to build pipline: no element tcppclientsrc

Tags: android, tcp, gstreamer

I am attempting to run a tcp/ip connection. I am using a version of the Android tutorial 3: Video. The link to the tutorial is here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/video.html?gi-language=c

The following is my gst_parse_launch.

```
    data->pipeline =
          gst_parse_launch ("tcpclientsrc host=192.168.22.25 port=5001 ! queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! 
decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false", &error);
      if (error) {
        gchar *message =
            g_strdup_printf ("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);
```

When I run the application, I receive the following error.

"Unable to build pipeline: no element tcpclientsrc"

I am unsure, how to resolve this issue. Can anyone explain how I can resolve this? Currently using  gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.18.0 & NDK 21.3.6528147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. For anyone with this particular issue in the future, you must check your **Android.mk** file, make sure GSTREAMER_PLUGINS has all the required plugins for what you require.

Plugins can be found here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/for-android-development.html?gi-language=c